# How to rollback to a previous commit in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a previous commit sha. How do I roll back to a previous commit in Jenkins?

I have a main project with submodules.

I'm thinking I can pass in the previous commit sha to the build parametrized field. Also, I have submodules, how do I rollback the submodules to the previous commit using the main project commit sha?

Answer (score 0):

> how do I rollback the submodules to the previous commit using the main project commit sha?

You don't: [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) are, [by their nature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1979194/6309), fixed SHA1 recorded as **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, [special entries in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) of the main repo.

If you set the main repo to a previous SHA1, it will have with it the SHA1 that were recorded for the submodules.